# generate and using a precompiled library ESP32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, library

I would like to ask you how I can generate a `dot_a` file for a given library for ESP32? I want to replace my .cpp file with a precompiled `.a` in the Arduino IDE.
Is that possible? Can you please guide me?

Comment: Welcome, next time don't use bold text for an entire text. Also check the shift key.

Comment: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/library-specification/#precompiled-binaries